# Lua/ Torch - Error while creating train.t7 and test.t7 files using custom data set

Tags: lua, dataset, torch, training-data

I am trying to feed my own dataset to the CNN model I created. The code to create the training and testing `.t7` files is uploaded [here](https://github.com/syamprasadkr/learning_torch/blob/master/create_t7.lua).

I tested this code by creating a `train_set.t7` of 5000 images and `test_set.t7` of 500 images. Everything went well and I was able to load the images to the CNN model. Then I tried creating another set of `.t7` files from a larger dataset. I would like to explain a bit about the organization of the dataset. There is a `ROOT` folder called `data` (in the code, look for `ROOT`). There are two sub folders in it: `train` and `test`. Each of these sub folders are divided into 5 different folders named: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`. Each of these folders have around 70,000 images in the case of `train`.

The problem is that my code throws the following error after adding all the files from `data/train/1`:

```
 /home/ubuntu/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...e/ubuntu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchx/indexdir.lua:53: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value
stack traceback:
    ...e/ubuntu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchx/indexdir.lua:53: in function 'indexdir'
    create_t7.lua:25: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...untu/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0000cff9
```

I tried changing the order of folders, but it didn't help. What does this error indicate? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that that either `findFile` variable or shell command `wc -L 'findFile' | cut -f1 -d` on line `53` in [indexdir.lua](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/torchx/blob/master/indexdir.lua) results in **nil**.

```
local maxPathLength = tonumber(sys.fexecute(wc .. " -L '"
                                            .. findFile .. "' |"
                                            .. cut .. " -f1 -d' '")) + 1
```

So, basically lua attempts to perform `nil +1` operation which is an error.
Check carefully your `path_local` paths.

Comment: My `path_local` are right. I recently tried using this code in a machine with larger RAM and it worked. I am trying to see if there are better alternatives.

Comment: This might not be the "not enough" RAM issue but the `wc` shell command which results in `nil`. Do both machines run linux?

Comment: Yes. But the machine which throws the error is a Jetson TX1. The second machine is a Lenovo laptop.